# How can I export or find my db using SQLite +Flutter in local storage?

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, android-sqlite, sqflite

Hi I'm new in Flutter and I'm trying to use the data of my sqflite db or trying to export the information of it, I already try to find the db in my local storage but i cant find it using Android, How can I export or find my db..?

I alredy try using debug mode and installing the APK in my phone but I still can't find it....

I need to use the data in a SQL file or something else thats why I'm looking for the db in my local storage.

this is my code for create the db..

```dart
static Future<sql.Database> db() async { 
  return sql.openDatabase(
    'myfirstdb.db', 
    version: 1, 
    onCreate: (sql.Database database, int version) async { 
      await createTables(database); 
    }, 
  );
}
```

Comment: The SQLite database file will be saved in your [app's data directory](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47924/where-do-android-apps-store-data) using the name you passed to `openDatabase`. Using one of any number of Android file managers, you should be able to locate it easily.

Comment: I already try that and doesn't works